# Timestamp error when trying to view page revisions

Tags: theming, nodes

When trying to view a node revision at `<base_url>/node/<node_number>/revisions/<revision_number>/view/`, I get

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">InvalidArgumentException</em>: The timestamp must be numeric. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus::createFromTimestamp()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">200</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Component/Datetime/DateTimePlus.php</em>).
```

I `error_log`ed the value of that timestamp where it throws that error (in the core code) as I was digging into the problem, and it's a type `NULL`.

I do not fully understand the sequence of hooks that get called throughout the process of generating this preview that would cause a timestamp issue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do mean by sequence of hooks the call stack? Then enable full error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I get this on my log: ``` 
[25-Jul-2019 11:04:53] WARNING: [pool www] child 1168 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "The timestamp must be numeric." at /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Datetime/DateTimePlus.php line 200"
172.17.0.7 -  25/Jul/2019:11:04:15 +1000 "GET /index.php" 500```

Comment: I added this line on my settings.local.php `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
` Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks again

Comment: The error message you've posted is a wrong argument for a function. The question is which code is calling the function and why it is providing the wrong argument.